# What is the purpose of the [layer] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The excerpt for the [layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layer) tag says:

> This tag is ambiguous. Consider using more specific tags to better
>   reflect the question's content.

Why does this tag exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does this tag exist?

Probably because there are 1,216 questions tagged with it, and no one wants to take the burden to remove it from all of these questions.

If you have a look at the [excerpt history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20106415/revisions), that tag info was provided about a year ago. It is still true: The tag is ambiguous and should not be used.

Is your question a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)? To cite from the tag info there (emphasis mine):

> > **IMPORTANT**
> >     In practice, burnination means ***editing every question individually***, removing the tag and doing any other cleanup required. Moderators do not have any special tools for this purpose. The only folks who can summarily remove a tag are the SE developers (and maybe the Community Managers), but they seldom take that action themselves unless the tag is especially egregious. There are [very specific cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/213575) when tag burnination is necessary and how to approach a tag burnination request.

Comment: If there is no good discription for this tag so where should be used ?

Comment: @Arman The description is a warning that the tag should not be used, and that's good so. Before there was no description at all. And no, as the description says, the tag should not be used.

Comment: If this tag has no discription and should not be used , why 1.2k question used it and have 15 followers?

Comment: Because not everyone in the world is a responsible tagger out there, believe it or not.

Comment: That's interesting... I don't see why it cannot be removed by a query over those questions. This tag is like "Oh, and this code contains layers, I understand it better now".

Comment: Various drawing environments contain layers. On iOS and OS X, for example, there are "layers". That said, nothing wrong with this request - there are better ways to talk about layering in graphics.

Comment: @Moshe Every software architecture is build in _layers_, etc. The tag doesn't add any value.

Comment: I don't mean the conceptual layers. I mean visual layers.